# "Guarding" WCF service from certain users - application identity

Tags: wcf, wcf-security

We are using WCF services. Right now, we are using Windows Auth but this is not for long. Some services will sit outside the firewall and use username/password verified in the database.

My tech lead is "scared" at how easy any user can "Add Reference" to the services we have and just party on. He wants to "guard" the services by adding another identity - the application. He wants the service to accept requests from certain applications so the certain users cannot just use the service - add reference to it and call. It’s the notion of the application having an identity + credentials that is the operative principle here, as services on the network may need to authenticate those credentials prior to fulfilling a request, in order to prevent rogue code inside the network (i.e., NOT the application) from accessing services using “Joe User” end-user credentials.

Does this make any sense?

Then he believes the Juval Lowy's book has, in an Appendix that discusses sending more than one identity during a WCF call (Security Interceptor).  There is no specific suggestion that all of those have to be end-user identities and if that is the case, one of those could be the identity of the application making the request.

How can this be done?

Thanks,
Sam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with sending an application identity is that the secret used to confirm that identity has to be stored somewhere. If it is visible to one application on a machine then generally it will be visible to other applications running under the same identity.

Would your manager be happy with "it came from an authorised machine"? If that's the case you could simply use Client Certs

Its also worth taking a step back: if the user is authenticated and is authorized to perform the functionality they have requested, why do you care which application they came from - if they are who they say they are and they are allowed to do what they are requesting then why couldn't they use, say, fiddler to make the request - isn't that the point of a service (rather than a closely coupled client server app)?

Comment: Could you expand on "simply use Client certs?" How do you have an "authorized machine?"

Comment: Well if you install a client cert on a machine (including the private key) then use that cert for authentication you are proving the machine has an authorised cert on it, Certificate based authentication is already built into the WCF security model (which is why I said "simply")

Comment: >then generally it will be visible to other applications running >under the same identity.   --- I think he is talking about each application having a different identity

Comment: But as I said - how do you give an application an identity backed up by a secret such that the secret cannot be discovered by a malicious user?

Comment: Ok, here is his reaction to your idea: IIRC a certificate was one of the options we were looking at – ditto with how it integrates into WCF: does it use the same Identity / Principal mechanism used to authenticate end users’ Windows accounts (and other sources), or some other (possibly opaque) mechanism?  If it’s “built into the WCF security model” then perhaps it works differently… we just need to find out how, is all.

Comment: One other question we had discussed about certificates, and other forms of identity, was: does Windows provide a way to cryptographically wrap/unwrap a certificate / identity with an administrator password or similar ‘live’ secret, so that it’s useless to a rogue process unless they also have the password?  If not then Richard Blewett’s point that “the secret … has to be stored somewhere” is pertinent (i.e., if the secret is stored in the administrator’s head, then what’s installed on the machine isn’t such an issue ;).

Comment: Likewise, if only the administrator can set up an application to run under a given identity, then the secret used to confirm the identity is visible to only the applications that are supposed to see it, and the identity is protected… less so if this isn’t the case.  Also may need to be confirmed or checked.

Comment: OK so we're not talking about end-user applications then. In that case, get the application to run under a specific unique identity and either put a cert in the user store for that identity or put a cert in the local machine store but ACL it for just the application identity. If you want to send both the user and the application identity then you may want to look at using SAML tokens and putting claims for both the user and application identity

Comment: Now, I am confused again. We already decided to go together with certificates. Last questions: Certificates require a WSHttpBinding of some sort right? Thats why they are use in Internet scenarios? It needs this because there is a WS-Trust negotitaion of the keys? In other words, we cannot use NetTcpBinding with Certicates or can we? WE always talk about a "front" computer in the DMZ that will be exposed to the Internet talking to a "back" computer with the WCF services? Does it matter because we will always talk to the services in the back? Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Certs can be used with pretty much any binding - WSHttpBinding (if you have intermediaries) NetTcpBinding, BasicHttpBinding or some custom flavor such as Binary over HTTP

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look through [Common Security Scenarios](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730301.aspx) in the MSDN documentation to see if any of those options fit your needs.

The options that pops to my eye are [Transport Security with Certificate Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731074.aspx) and [Message Security with Mutual Certificates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733102.aspx).  Both rely on X.509 certificates.  The latter option is on the message level, so you can handle certificate delivery and security negotiation however you want.

Answer (score 0):

To make it a lot harder for someone to add a reference to your service you could just remove the mex endpoint.  This way it would be very difficult for a stranger to create a valid request message.

You can then distribute the WSDL manually, only to people you trust.